# NOT IN clause for DynamoDB Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with a primary key ID. I want to be able to filter results by ID. In SQL I would do something like `WHERE id NOT 'IN (1, 2, 3)'`

In my DynamoDB Query I have the following params

```
// existingResponseIds == [1,2]

const params = {
    IndexName: 'onDate-index',
    TableName: AppConstants.ALEXA_DB_RESPONSE_TABLE_NAME,
    KeyConditionExpression: "#onDate = :onDate",
    FilterExpression : "NOT #id IN (:idValue)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
      "#onDate": "onDate",
      "#id": "id"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":onDate": date,
      ":idValue" : existingResponseIds
    }
  };
```

However it is still returning items with `id` of 1 and 2. Does this kind of filter even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. FilterExpression in DynamoDb actually cost the Same Capacity as applying no filters so incase if you're trying to save RCU then this might not be a good idea. You can do an application-level Filtering by getting the data into your server and then using a filter on the array of items you get back from the query(without filter). Note (I use something arr.filter(data=>predicate(data)) works elegantly for me in Javascript(Nodejs)).
2. On the other hand Lets say the result of this query is large and you're trying to save bandwidth by getting a smaller amount of data to be transferred

   ```
   FilterExpression: "NOT( #id IN (:id0, :id1, :id2) )",
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
       "#id": "id"
   },
   ExpressionAttributeValues: {
       ":id0": 'data_1'
       ":id1": ...
   }
   ```

The Above You have to generate by enumerating like if I were in your case I would do something of this sort assuming ids is the array

```
let idList =  ids.map((id,i)=> `:id${i}`).join(','); // ":id0,:id1..."
FilterExpression: `NOT(#id in (${idList})`
```

Something Similar for the Expression Attribute Values as well